# Does this index in postgres make sense?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, hash

I made a very simple DB in Postgres containing these two tables:

Singer (**ID**, name, surname, birthday)

Song (**ID**, name, album, year, singer)

**ID** in table Singer is of type serial and it's its primary key.

**ID** in table Song is of type serial and it's its primary key.

The column "singer" in the Song table references ID in the Singer table

I want to retrieve ***all the songs of a given singer (let's say the singer having id = 3) and the singer's name and surname***.

Therefore I need a query like this:

```
SELECT song.name, song.album, song.year, singer.name, singer.surname
FROM song, singer
WHERE song.singer = singer.id AND singer.id = 3
```

I created then an hash index on the "singer" column in the Song table for optimizing the join operation:

```
CREATE INDEX ON song USING hash (singer);
```

However, if I execute the query and use explain/analyze, my index seems not to be used.

So my question is: does an index like this make sense or not?

If not, is this because the column "singer" in the song table is a foreign key which references a primary key (id) in the singer table and Postgres automatically creates indexes on primary keys (so my custom index is not needed because basically it's quite the same thing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: never use a `hash` index as they will become corrupted on a server crash, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html#INDEXES-TYPES).

Yes, this index will definitely help, since the optimizer should choose a *nested loop join* with `song` as the *inner table* in this case.

Note that it is almost always the right thing to create an index on the column(s) on which you define a foreign key constraint, otherwise any `DELETE` on `singer` will lead to a *sequential scan* on `song`.

Comment: I'm sorry let's say I want all songs of a given singer (just one)

Would the hash index I wrote in the original post have sense then or not?

I've edited the original post with the right query

Comment: Also, I have to choose between hash or btree indexes. Hash is good for accessing single values, while btree is good for accessing intervals of values. 

In this case the specific singer is needed, therefore I chose the hash index.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer. You should *never ever* use a hash index, because any crash will corrupt your database. Your understanding of B-tree indexes in incorrect, they work just fine in your case.